# Load WPF themes based on Monitor Resolution

Tags: wpf, app-themes

I facing quite big problem with resolution in my WPF app, which will be used in **Hospital**s, customer is asked for BIG fonts and Controls so that they can see data clearly from the distance.

The problem is now when application runs in 800X600 resolution, whole UI will get messed up, so I thought to define another theme for lower monitor resolution, now **how I could load themes from C# code ??**

**OR you guys got better idea??**

Comment: (less knowlegde in WPF). But was WPF designed to solve these kind of issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be able solve this issue with the [Viewbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx) control. Paste this XAML into a new Window and run it.

```
<Viewbox>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button>One</Button>
        <Button>Two</Button>
        <Button>Three</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Viewbox>
```

When the Window is re-sized, the contents including fonts are scaled.

For some reason, the designer in Visual Basic 2008 Express fails to paint anything inside the Viewbox. That may be a deal-breaker for you if it happens in Pro or TS.

Comment: Even in VSTS it doesn't paint anything... but Expression blend does :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](http://dotnet.org.za/rudi/archive/2009/03/14/flexible-layout-on-steroids.aspx) article. It uses the SizeTemplateControl from PhotoSuru to show different layouts based on the screen res or window size!